# Github choose who can create issues on a public repository

Tags: github

I have a public repository on Github and I like using the issue tracking system to keep track of bugs, tasks, milestones etc. but I don't want just anyone to be able to create issues.

Is there any way to make it so only collaborators of the project can create issues on my public repository. I know I can set the privacy of issues on Bitbucket but is there a similar ability on Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that feature is not available in Github public repo , for that you need to purchase the private repository